# Mesh (with bones) keyable in pose mode

Tags: mesh, bones, pose-mode

I made an animation controller using meshes for a vehicle I am building. The rig is a combination of other mesh controllers and bones. I'm new to blender and just went on and built the vehicle and rig, but I couldn't figure out that how to key objects in pose-mode. Is there a way of keeping my "fancy" mesh controllers without replacing them with bones?

[image: Mesh control]

Comment: Pose mode is for one model at once (and for bones). If you want to keyframe objects you have to do it in Object mode. The object and rig animations are work together, so you don't have to rig all the meshes.

Comment: See if I got this clear. I can only animate bones and one mesh in pose mode. If I have a other meshes, I need to  animate those in object mode? Thanks

Comment: Yes Object mode is for managing your objects. All other modes applies for the selected object only. (There are some extra features for example you can be in Edit mode with multiple meshes, but this is just a convenience function it has limitations. Or in Weight Paint mode you can handle the armature and the mesh at the same time).